# CodeIgniter HMVC: Correct way of communicating with other modules?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

Lets say I have 2 modules: A and B.

If I want to call a function in one of the models of module B from module A, what is the correct way?

Should the communication between modules only happen between controllers or I can call directly a model from module B in a controller form module A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the steps below

```
1) load model of B from A module like $this->load->model("b_model");

2) if your function name is user then call like this $this->b_model->user();
```

Comment: So is this considered "best practice"? I will have to couple every model I use to a controller from another module?

Comment: Do you have any kind of source or article I could refer to? 

Wouldn't it be better designed if the communication happened between controllers? Because of less coupling?